# disable chrome suggestions while entering a form field vale

Tags: html, google-chrome, autofill

When i enter some field value in a form in my application. chrome is suggesting some values previously entered. I wanted to disable it. How could i do that. Any help is appreciated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Answer (score 1):

It should have same id for autocomplete value, just put 
`autocomplete="foo"` or use a different id so that it doesn't match and it shouldn't be filled